# Relation between bandwidth and data rate

Tags: frequency, nyquist, bandwidth

I have trouble understanding the following from wikipedia - Bandwidth (Signal Processing)

> A key characteristic of bandwidth is that any band of a given width can carry the same amount of information, regardless of where that band is located in the frequency spectrum

The higher the frequency the more the cycles and therefore shouldn't there be more information passing in a second?

Comment: 200 Hz wide band carries same amount of information for any location in the frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure never changing sinusoidal carrier of a given frequency carries no information.  Changes or modulations to that carrier over time (as in: per second) can carry information.  The maximum rate of information is related to the bandwidth and S/N ratio, not the number of unmodulated carrier cycles.

Of course, it may be easier to implement certain modulation schemes with a higher carrier to bandwidth ratio.